# Locally deploy android app updates

Tags: android, local

I am wanting the create an Android app that will only be used internally. The App needs to communicate with a locally hosted server to check for and download updates. What is the best way to achieve this and are there any pre-existing solutions?

Comment: by `locally hosted server` you mean to say a server in LAN without a public IP ?

Comment: I have [an open source component](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater) that I am working on for this, but it is still pretty new.